# Include my own services in DSpace 6 unit test

Tags: java, junit, dspace

I'm trying to do a test in DSpace 6, but my service is Null when i run the test. I test it in a servlet and work correctly, but the test not work

My Test:

```
public class PonderationServiceTest extends AbstractUnitTest {

    /** log4j category */
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RecomendationManualServiceTest.class);

    protected WorkspaceItemService workspaceItemService = ContentServiceFactory.getInstance().getWorkspaceItemService();
    protected InstallItemService installItemService = ContentServiceFactory.getInstance().getInstallItemService();
    protected CollectionService collectionService = ContentServiceFactory.getInstance().getCollectionService();
    protected CommunityService communityService = ContentServiceFactory.getInstance().getCommunityService();
    protected EPersonService ePersonService = EPersonServiceFactory.getInstance().getEPersonService();
    protected ItemService itemService = ContentServiceFactory.getInstance().getItemService();

    private PonderationService ponderationService = //<-- THIS NOT WORK. NullPointerException here !!!!
            PonderationServiceFactory.getInstance().getPonderationService(); 

    private Community community;
    private Collection collection;
    private WorkspaceItem workspaceItem;
    private EPerson eperson;
    private Item item;

    @Before
    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();

        try {
            context.turnOffAuthorisationSystem();

            eperson = ePersonService.create(context);

            community = communityService.create(null, context);
            collection = collectionService.create(context, community);
            workspaceItem = workspaceItemService.create(context, collection, false);
            item = installItemService.installItem(context, workspaceItem);
            context.commit();

        }catch (SQLException | AuthorizeException ex)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            context.restoreAuthSystemState();
        }

    }

    @Test
    public void testCreate() throws Exception
    {
        context.turnOffAuthorisationSystem();

        Ponderation ponderation = new Ponderation();
        ponderation.setDateCreated(new Date());
        ponderation.setValue(5);
        ponderation.setItem(item);
        ponderation.setEPerson(eperson);

        log.info("Ponderation: " + ponderation);

        Assert.assertNotNull(ponderation);

        // Persist 
        ponderationService.create(context, ponderation); // <-- NullPointerException
        context.complete();
        context.restoreAuthSystemState();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I run the test:

```
mvn -pl dspace-api  -Dtest=org.dspace.content.PonderationServiceTest -Dmaven.test.skip=false test
```

and this is the output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.dspace.content.PonderationServiceTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 12.55 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.dspace.content.PonderationServiceTest
testCreate(org.dspace.content.PonderationServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.007 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.dspace.content.PonderationServiceTest.<init>(PonderationServiceTest.java:34)


Results :

Tests in error: 
  PonderationServiceTest.<init>:34 NullPointer

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

DSpace services work correctly
I can not find my mistake, I do not know if it will be some configuration that I'm missing

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more information on what isn't working. What errors do you get?

Comment: @AdiBradfield Thanks for your fast answer, i edit my question.